# Make height of layout wrap only one of child views

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have RelativeLayout and inside it, there is an ImageView and a TextView, in that order. I want the ImageView to have height of match_parent but I want the RelativeLayout to have height of wrap_content of the TextView inside it. How can I make it so?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please some images for what you want and exactly what happening with you code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it will work as I understand your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CC0000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:background="#FF9966"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/content"
          android:layout_alignTop="@+id/content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#FF3399"
        android:text="asdjajdasdjajdasdjaddtegrgfhfhfhfhhfh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />
  </RelativeLayout>
```